# Custom Array displaying badly in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a custom array of string urls which im adding to an image_tag as below:

```
<%=  @attachment.each do |att| %>
<div>
    <%= image_tag att %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Images are displayed correctly but im getting the below junk underneath the images:

["http://localhost:8090/download/attachments/884794/DSC_0006.NEF?            version=1&modificationDate=1343685834627", "http://localhost:8090/download/attachments/885137/Sunflower.gif?version=1&modificationDate=1343720588175", "http://localhost:8090/download/attachments/885140/Spiked.gif?version=1&modificationDate=1343720548736"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the very first tag to <% instead of <%=. The equals prints the junk return value of .each.

Comment: awesome, also how would i create a link_to on this? so when the image is clicked it goes to an url?

Comment: would it also be possible to pass another parameter such as a pageid which i can work with in the controller? this data is coming from an external xmlrpc call, so i can't use the goodies that rails offers, or can i save data into a fake rails model and be able to use it like a normal rails model?