# Rails displaying a string as an array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

First off, I apologize in advance for any incorrect terms or general misunderstanding of ruby/rails/html that I may display in this question, as I'm still learning the languages and how they work. I've been given a gui to work on and fix bugs for and after upgrading from rails 3.0 to 3.2 I'm seeing artifacts in many places.

Specifically what I'm asking in this post though is a string display issue. The short version of what I have is a message thread displayed with in a web page that looks close to what you'd see in most text message clients on smartphones now days. The page displays a persons name if the system knows who they are (registered with us) and just a mobile number if they are not.

However the issue is that instead of displaying 5554440002, it's displaying as:
["(", "5", "5", "5", ")", " ", "4", "4", "4", "-", "0", "0", "0", "1"]

Looking around the net, and on stack overflow I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735669/custom-array-displaying-badly-in-rails-view) To be the closest thing to answering my issue. However the suggestion of dropping the = out of <%= ends in the mobile number no longer displaying.

The line of code that generates this output is:

```
<%= find_associated_account conversation_message['from'] -%>
```

Edit 1 (definition):

```
  def find_associated_account(input)
    if input[0..0] == $operator.domestic_code.to_s
      input = input[1..10]
    end
    if @account.associated_accounts and @account.associated_accounts.count > 0      
      if !(input.match(/@/)) && !(input.match(/MISSING_MAILBOX/))
        input = input[0..9]
      end
      begin
        acc = @account.associated_accounts.find_by_number(input)
        if acc
          return get_display_name_for_account(acc)
        end
    end
    return format_mdn(input)
  end

  def format_mdn(input)
    domestic_length = $operator.domestic_mask.count('#')
    number_cc_stripped = input.sub(/\A[#{$operator.domestic_code}]/, '')
    if /^[0-9]{#{domestic_length}}$/.match(number_cc_stripped)
      result = []
      count = 0
      $operator.domestic_mask.each_char do |c|
        if c == '#'
          result << number_cc_stripped[count,1]
          count += 1
        else
          result << c
        end        
      end
      return result.to_s
    end
    return input
  end
```

Any advice given will be greatly appreciated and any other information needed will be provided.

Comment: if you provide us with definitions of this methods it'll be great...

Comment: Solved it after messing with the return value of format_mdn

Comment: `result.to_s` is going to give you the string representation of an array, if you want to make it into a real string, `.join("")`

Comment: @DaveNewton That also worked. Might go with that as it doesn't change the existing code as much as the solution I posted. Thanks.

Comment: The `<<` string op is string concatenation; it should work too. You don't need to convert the string to a string via `to_s`, though, it already is one.

Comment: @MumblesCrzy so only you needed is to dig into method defs... :)

Comment: @ryaz Yeah I felt bad about finding a solution so quick after posting, but I'm keeping it up just in case someone else needs the information.   DaveNewton helped clean it up a bit though, so I'm glad I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this after messing with the return value of format_mdn. I changed the initialization of result to "" instead of [] which I'm guessing changed the type of the variable? In any case the final code for this definition is:

```
def format_mdn(input)
  domestic_length = $operator.domestic_mask.count('#')
  number_cc_stripped = input.sub(/\A[#{$operator.domestic_code}]/, '')

  if /^[0-9]{#{domestic_length}}$/.match(number_cc_stripped)
    result = []
    count = 0
    $operator.domestic_mask.each_char do |c|
      if c == '#'
        result << number_cc_stripped[count,1]
        count += 1
      else
        result << c
      end        
    end
    return result.join("")
  end
  result = number_cc_stripped
  return result
end
```